# Detached process still dies with parent

Tags: background-process, daemon, nohup

I am trying to detach a process completely from a bash script, and then kill the bash script with Ctrl+C and have the detached process keep running. My code currently looks like this:

```
nohup ${SHELL} -c "env ID='0' \
env DIR=\"$(dirname -- "${input_file}")\" \
$DIR/encode-scripts/encode.pl > /dev/null; \
mv "$DIR/encode-scripts/output/$HASH" "${output_folder}"" & disown
```

The process detaches successfully, and the bash script continues to execute. However, as soon as I kill the bash script with Ctrl+C (during an arbitrary loop), I see from logs that the `ffmpeg` program inside of the sub-process shows: `Exiting normally, received signal 2.` The `encode.pl` script which spawns `ffmpeg` then continues, but how can I stop `ffmpeg` from dying prematurely? I thought this was what `nohup` was supposed to do.

Comment: `nohup` ignores SIGHUP, but doesn't necessarily do anything about SIGINT (i.e., it is doing what it's supposed to do).

Comment: @muru how can I stop SIGINT from propagating to the child processes?

Comment: See if `setsid` helps: https://superuser.com/a/709423/334516

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a simple test. Try this: create a shell script containing just two lines `nohup sh -c "sleep 30" & disown` and `sleep 300`. Run the script. Press `C-c` and then enter `pgrep -a sleep`. It should return a single entry for the `sleep 30`, which is what it is doing for me. What does it do for you?

Comment: The `disown` should be sufficient to isolate the child from the SIGINT...

Comment: @muru using `setsid ... &` works perfectly. @user1404316 I think the reason that the code does not reproduce the issue is because the SIGINT propagates from the parent process because it is in the foreground. With an empty terminal different behaviour should be expected. And apparently `disown` was not sufficient, nor necessary.